# if page is parent page redirect to first child with hook / polylang

Tags: templates, hooks

I'm trying to check, before a page is rendered, if this page is a page with childs. If this is true, I would like to redirect to the first child page based on menu_order.

I don't want to add the following code in every template, so i thought the best way is to use a hook.

The following code works in a template, but not on the startpage if the polylang plugin is activated. (The error is: Trying to get property of non-object).

Is there something different on the Polylang startpage? If I'm accessing domain.com/en/startpage, it is working fine. If I'm accessing domain.com then polylang is redirecting to domain.com/en/ and it is not working.

```
function weParentPageRedirect() {

    global $post;

    // get child pages
    $child_page = get_pages( "child_of=" . $post->ID . "&sort_column=menu_order" );

    if ( $child_page ) {
        // get id of first child page
        $firstchild = $child_page[0];
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $firstchild->ID ), 301 );
        exit();
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'weParentPageRedirect' );
```

The function **get_queried_object** returns the following:

On the page domain.com/en/startpage where it is working:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 6
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2016-10-28 16:39:54
    [post_date_gmt] => 2016-10-28 14:39:54
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => Startpage
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => startpage
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2016-11-05 21:58:58
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-11-05 20:58:58
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://domain.com/?page_id=6
    [menu_order] => 1
    [post_type] => page
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

On the page domain.com/en/ where it is not working:

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 6
    [name] => English
    [slug] => en
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 6
    [taxonomy] => language
    [description] => a:3:{s:6:"locale";s:5:"en_EN";s:3:"rtl";i:0;s:9:"flag_code";s:2:"en";}
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 42
    [filter] => raw
)
```

The question is:
Could I check if $post is empty, and if it is empty use the function get_queried_object and use the term_id for get_pages?

Thanks!

Comment: what does the result of [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) contain?

Comment: @Milo please see me updated question

Comment: hmm, maybe check what's in `$wp_query->posts`. you'll probably need `global $wp_query;` first.